# Reading a file of digits into a linked list

Tags: c, file, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I don't get any error; the code works but it's showing only first element and doesn't show others. I want to show all of the numbers in file with linked list. What is my mistake?

The numbers in `numbers.txt`:

```
9 2 3
4 2 3
1 2 9
2 4 8
7 5 9
2 4 7
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NUMBERS{
    int katsayi;
    int taban;
    int us;
    NUMBERS *next;
};

int main(){
    NUMBERS *temp=NULL;
    NUMBERS *list=NULL; // to keep first element
    NUMBERS *head=NULL; // temp for the first element
    FILE *fp=fopen("numbers.txt","r+");
    while(!feof(fp)){
        temp=(NUMBERS*)malloc(sizeof(NUMBERS));
        fscanf(fp,"%d %d %d",&temp->katsayi,&temp->taban,&temp->us);
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(list==NULL){
            list=temp;
        }
        else{
            head=list;
            while(head->next!=NULL){
                head=head->next;
            }
            head=temp;
        }

    }
    head=list; 
    while(head!=NULL){  
        printf("%d %d %d",head->katsayi,head->taban,head->us);
        head=head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the end of your `else` part, you do `head=temp`. So what exactly is the point in all of the `head=...` assignments which take place prior to that??? You may as well get rid of all of them (including that `while` loop), and be left with `head=temp`. I am hopeful that this will lead you to the problem, since it obviously wasn't your intention to just do `head=temp`.

Comment: Yes my bad :/ , thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- `while(!feof(fp)){` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) because it tells us when we've read past the end of the file, not when we're at the last line (see link for details). You can check whether the return of `fscanf != EOF`. I'm assuming the blank lines in your post are a formatting error, but if they aren't, you can use the return value of `fscanf` to make sure all 3 digits were matched and skip any lines where they weren't.
- The code shouldn't compile because `NUMBERS` hasn't been `typedef`'d. No need for this to be in all caps, which is usually reserved for constants.
- [No need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to cast the result of `malloc` in C.
- The code to insert a new node:

  ```
      head=list;
      while(head->next!=NULL){
          head=head->next;
      }
      head=temp;
  ```

  doesn't make much sense. After traversing the list, `head` is simply set to `temp`, undoing the traversal. We shouldn't be traversing the entire list just to add a single node in any case. The solution is to use a `tail` node which always points to the last element in the list.
- The code leaks memory. `free` every `malloc`.
- Check for errors when opening the file and exit gracefully.
- Consider a `LinkedList` struct which encapsulates head/tail pointers and has corresponding insertion/removal/traversal/free functions. `main` should be broken into functions as well (exercise for the reader).

Here's an initial rewrite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Numbers {
    int katsayi;
    int taban;
    int us;
    struct Numbers *next;
} Numbers;

int main() {
    Numbers *temp = NULL;
    Numbers *list = NULL; 
    Numbers *tail = NULL; 
    Numbers dummy;
    char file[] = "numbers.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d: could not open %s \n", 
                __FILE__, __LINE__, file);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", 
           &dummy.katsayi, &dummy.taban, &dummy.us) != EOF) {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
        memcpy(temp, &dummy, sizeof(*temp));
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (list) {
            tail->next = temp;
        }
        else {
            list = temp;
        }

        tail = temp;
    }

    for (temp = list; temp; temp = temp->next) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", 
               temp->katsayi, temp->taban, temp->us);
    }

    for (temp = list; temp;) {
        Numbers *prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(prev);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
9 2 3
4 2 3
1 2 9
2 4 8
7 5 9
2 4 7
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it's working now . Your code taught a lot of things